# How to Copy Data Validation Rules from one Cell to Another in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The following code isn't copying the data validation rules from cell H1 to the target cell.

Cell H1 does indeed contain a data validation dropdown list so there is something to copy.

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?:

```
' Copy data validation rules for new rows
    
wsSource.Cells(1, "H").Copy
wsTarget.Cells(lastRow_Trg + i, "H").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation
```

Comment: The code looks good. I have tested it w/o any issure on Excel 365.

Comment: Also tested and works fine for me ... could there be something in the wider context of your code and/or the relevant Worksheets that is preventing the paste operation from working e.g. target Worksheet is protected and, somewhere in the procedure (or call stack) you have `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: What kind of validation rules do you try copying? Than, using `Target`,  most probably the code slice is part of an event. Without seeing it and without mentioning **what error is it raised**, it is really difficult to be helped. At least, do you have `Application.EnableEvents= False` before and `Application.EnableEvents= True`, after?